# Javascript find element And click without css class

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML like

```
<ul class="sortword"> 
    <li>
        <div>ABC</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>DEF</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I use Javascript to find and click `<div>DEF</div>` tags

Comment: Multiple ways of doing this but **When** are you expecting this `javascript` to execute and how many other elements on the page use the `class` name `sortword`?

Comment: what do you mean by `find`

Comment: I can see many good answers below so I thought I would offer a different approach. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eo4yur7j/) this method will use `querySelectorAll` to target the specific `ul` and `document.evaluate` to filter/find the div with expected content. You can modify this into a function so it can be used for multiple elements or filtering.

Comment: Also here is an example of turning this method into a function so you won't be limited to one specific item. [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0m4wnkdd/)

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to find ABC and click it OR find DEF to click it

Comment: That last demo will give you the option of finding those `divs` and clicking them but without knowing **WHEN** you expect this to execute or the **conditions** to find ABC OR DEF then it's hard to give you a solid solution. If you can explain when you want this "click" to trigger and are you wanting to trigger this based on which content exists or are you wanting it to trigger for both? You question is lacking important detail so please provide that and you will find people will provide better solutions based on what you want.

Comment: I see you have changed the structure of the `HTML` but my example still functions for this. [**JsFiddle Update**](https://jsfiddle.net/0m4wnkdd/1/)

Comment: I don't want use  onclick="alert(this.textContent+' clicked.');

Comment: The `onclick` attribute is there for demo purposes to show that the element has been clicked otherwise how will you know that element has been clicked from my example? The same for the last example I have posted, the buttons on there are to show how you can use a function call to target a specific filter but isn't necessary. As I have said, you need to explain more of how you expect this to function otherwise it's guessing games for everyone and you don't get the solution you want.

Comment: If you have multiple `div`'s with the content **DEF** then this edited example will also work! [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vroarqyt/) this will be my last example until the relevant detail of your expectations is added to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).forEach((div) => {
    if (div.textContent.trim() === "DEF") {
        let evt = new Event('click');
        div.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a very good approach but this is targeting every within the page as you can see from the `console.log()`'s withing this  [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k1q2ck73/) So would it not be better to target the specific class and the div elements? Minor change but seems more logical than running a `forEach()` on unnecessary elements. [**JsFiddle Selector Change**](https://jsfiddle.net/yxyyrchj/) one small change- `document.querySelectorAll('.sortword div')`

Answer (score 0):

## JQuery

Use the [:contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

`$("div:contains('DEF')").click()`

Comment: ... there's also a non-jquery answer but this question seems downvoted.

Comment: Since `jQuery` isn't tagged or mentioned in the question I think it would be relevant/important for you to give minor detail about including the `jQuery` **library* and maybe turn this into a working snippet for better example purposes? It's good that you have included a link to the documentation the  `:contains() Selector` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery by selecting multiple elements and looping through them, but using it will make this a very short and easily readable code snippet. Be sure to include JQuery on your page using a link like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$( '.sortword li div' ).on( 'click', function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});

$( '.sortword li div' ).each( function() {
  $( this ).click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sortword"> 
<li>
    <div>ABC</div>
    <div>DEF</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to find ABC and click it OR find DEF to click it
Not the last child

Comment: This requires the client to click which removes the reason for asking how to trigger the `click` event from finding a specific element. also this doesn't even target the specific element, this just binds a click event for each div within the class `.sortword` and child of `ul`,

Comment: True, but the question is unclear but the op keeps slowly clarifying the requirements as answers are being added. Since the op is still checking, I'll keep guessing what the expected results are. Edited to trigger the clicks via jQuery and not just to listen for them.

Comment: @JasonB This is why I only offer minor examples within comments unless/until the question becomes clear of expectation. That allows me to give a solid answer rather than guessing and possibly giving the wrong answer or sending the OP in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("sortword")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
```

```html
<ul class="sortword"> 
    <li>
        <div>ABC</div>
        <div>DEF</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't trigger the `click` event for a `div` with specific content so this isn't what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Also this will only target the first *list item* `li` with all of the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textContent` as illustrated in the following code:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(‘ul li div’), desire;
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i ++) {
   if (el[i].textContent === 'DEF') { desire = el[i]; } 
   break;
}
```

Then use can use `desire` variable later on.

Comment: Once again, this will target **ALL** `div` in the DOM and loop through them which is unnecessary.

Comment: @NewToJS That’s how he want. He doesn’t want to add a class or an id, so how can I optimize the code?

Comment: If you run this and look in the browser console you will see it logs **All** `div`s within the page which your solution is doing [**Your Selector**](https://jsfiddle.net/tfsum7ac/) but the `break;` is also causing problems preventing this from every being a working solution. With a simple selector change you can see from viewing the console this will [**Only return ul/li/divs**](https://jsfiddle.net/73adr7ej/) which would be much more convenient.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't better because your `break;` is still going to cause problems and you should be using `document.querySelectorAll()` **not** `querySelectorAll()`. Please run your source code before posting it. I would also recommend you use the correct quotation marks within the source code you display.

Comment: **break;** is executing before looping to the next element no matter of the return from the `if` condition. You are using  a shorthand condition but if you contain it  `if(condition){source if true}` then your break will not cause an issue for storing *one* element within the variable.

Comment: @NewToJS sorry, it is about the editing. About the quotation marks, I’m using mobile app